# Git - how to delete a branch?

Tags: git, parameters, branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch)

I created a branch by mistake which starts with hyphen - , in starting character. For example

```
git checkout -b -z/username/workname  origin
```

if I try to delete the branch using

```
git branch -D -z/username/workname
```

git is throwing an parser error

```
error: unknown switch `z' usage: git
 branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged |
 --no-merged]    or: git branch [options] [-l] [-f] <branchname> 
 [<start-point>]    or: git branch
 [options] [-r] (-d | -D) <branchname> 
 or: git branch [options] (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
```

How do I delete a branch?

Comment: very possible duplicate of [Deleting a badly named git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch)

Answer (score 7):

Use -- to separate the -args from the non-dash args.  IE:

```
git branch -D -- -z/username/workname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/-z/username/workname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the branch with:

```
git branch -D /-z/username/workname
```