# Delete a branch starting with a hyphen

Tags: git

I managed to create a branch in git called '-f'

e.g.

```
$ git branch
* (no branch)
   -f
```

How do I delete the dang thing? 
git branch -d -f won't work, nor will git branch -d '-f' or even git branch -d -f -f

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a badly named git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
git branch -d -- -f
```

The `--` symbol in general will stop parsing of command line options with many Linux tools.

Another way is

```
git update-ref -d refs/heads/-f
```

but `git-update-ref` is rather dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will work, but a `--` argument in Unix/Linux-style commands often tells the command that you're done passing options, and now you're passing real arguments:

```
git branch -d -- '-f'
```

Comment: The quotes around `-f` are superfluous.

Comment: How about 2 dashes? :). I used a GUI tool to take care of it for now.

Answer (score 2):

I created a branch accidentally with the following:

```bash
git branch –show-current
```

I was able to use `grep` and `xargs` to specify a unique pattern to delete it:

```bash
git branch | grep "show-current" | xargs git branch -D
```

Answer (score 0):

I foolishly named a branch starting with a hyphen, and then checked out master.  I didn't want to **delete** my branch, I had work in it.

Neither of these worked:

`git checkout -dumb-name`

`git checkout -- -dumb-name`

`"`s, `'`s and `\`s didn't help either.

This worked: go into your working copy's .git/refs/heads, find the filename "-dumb-name" (or whatever) and get the hash of the branch. Then:

```
git checkout {hash}
git checkout -b brilliant-name
git branch -d -- -dumb-name
```