# How can I get Git to delete a file whose name begins with hyphens?

Tags: git

I have added and committed a file `----MY_Session.php`. I left hyphens in the beginning by mistake. Now I want to delete this file, but when I try to run

```
git rm -----MY_Session.php
```

it throws the following error.

```
error: unknown option `---MY_Session.php'
usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

-n, --dry-run         dry run
-q, --quiet           do not list removed files
--cached              only remove from the index
-f, --force           override the up-to-date check
-r                    allow recursive removal
--ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
```

I tried all the options listed above but none of them worked.

How can I delete this file?

Comment: Try using the `--` symbol.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711356/delete-a-branch-starting-with-a-hyphen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
git rm -- ----MY_Session.php
```

The '--' should stop the parsing of command line options and consider `----MY_Session.php` as the filename.

Comment: Or use `./----MY_Session.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a glob pattern in your `git rm` call to remove your file without specifying the dashes:

```
git rm '*MY_Session.php'
```

Of course, you would want to make sure that this pattern won't match any *other* files besides **----MY_Session.php**.

Comment: *Of course, you would want to make sure that this pattern won't match any other files besides `----MY_Session.php`.* For more robustness, you could use `?` instead of `*`, as in `git rm '?---MY_Session.php'`.