# How do I see the difference in a single file between origin and master in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control

How do I see the difference between a local file (in Master) and the same file in the remote repository (origin) in git? When I do a `git fetch origin` and then do a `git diff master origin/master`. It shows me a huge list of changes, which is not really helpful for a lot of java files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git diff master origin/master -- file/to/compare`

The `--` is a convention that many programs use; it indicates that any parameters after it are not to be considered options, even if they start with a hyphen. Git extends this convention and uses `--` to indicate that the following parameters are files (and not branches or other refs, whose names may overlap with file names).

Actually, I believe the `--` is optional as long as you do not use file names which also exist as branches etc., but it's easier to always use it.

Also see the [git diff manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html). The "--" convention is explained in this question: 
[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch)