# Git keeps resetting my files after a hard reset?

Tags: git, git-reset

I tried this solution with no lucK: [How I can store some local changes that survives git reset --hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881851/how-i-can-store-some-local-changes-that-survives-git-reset-hard)

Basically I have a script on the server that deploys my git to sites. Even though I did:

`git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- config/production.ini`

Are there any solutions that'll allow me to successfully not have this config file being overridden each time?

My script does:

```
129           exec('git reset --hard', $output);
134           exec('git pull '.$this->_remote.' '.$this->_branch, $output);
```

So basically a `git reset` then `git pull`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't version-control your config file.

Presumably you have modifications to your `production.ini` file that you want to keep, but which are sensitive and shouldn't be version controlled.

This is *extremely* common, and the generally accepted solution is to have a `production.ini.example` which *is* version controlled, which is copied to an un-tracked file `production.ini` where you can make changes in production.

Comment: So would I `git rm` it and then push it?

Comment: `git mv` it to `production.ini.example`. Back up your *production* `production.ini` before you pull changes into production, and then restore it as an untracked file after.