# git pull changes from remote repo keeping the changes in local file

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

I have a modified file htmlpage.html  in my local project directory and i want pull changes for that file from remote branch on **bitbucket**  without effecting my local file changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

Comment: `git commit` local changes, `git pull`

Comment: Or if you want to track the two versions create a new branch...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of committing or creating a new branch, simply make sure, as I [explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), to have:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

From there, any git pull will automatically:

- stash your local changes
- update your current branch by replaying your local commits on top of the updated (fetched) remote branch ([`pull --rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull--r))
- re-apply your stashed changed to your `htmlpage.html`

Another approach, I [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16884309/6309):

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- htmlpage.html
# to cancel it:
git update-index --no-skip-worktree -- htmlpage.html
```

Save a copy of your file first, before testing a `git pull`: `htmlpage.html` snould remain unchanged.