# What's the difference between "git checkout" and "git checkout --"?

Tags: git

When under git you modify some files, using `git status`, comes out the following message:

```
On branch dev
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   script.php
```

So I usually used `git checkout -- script.php` to undo my edits, as suggested.

I found anyway, from a collegue, that `git checkout script.php` seems to accomplish the same result.

So, my question is: are `git checkout -- script.php` and `git checkout script.php` synonyms, or not?

Please, provide at least a link to some documentation that proves what you said. Thanks!

Comment: See also [What does “--” (double-dash) mean? (also known as “bare double dash”)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/8132).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have tag or branch named `script.php`, then `git checkout script.php` will checkout that tag or branch, while `git checkout -- script.php` will checkout the file in current branch.

Comment: It makes sense... but would you provide some link supporting what you just wrote? In order to accept your answer I want make sure there is nothing else.

Comment: @clami219 Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: @clami219 This is also clearly stated in `git help checkout` man page, example #1.