# How to delete a directory I (accidentally) named after an argument

Tags: git, bash, arguments, subdirectory

I have been playing around with submodules from git and installed my first one in the wrong directory.  Fixed easily enough, but when trying to delete recursively, I put the arguments/files in the wrong order and now I have a directory named `--force`.

I have tried various commands to remove it, among them `-rf` (Yes, I know the dangers of it) but I can't seem to get rid of this directory.  Instead, bash thinks that I'm calling an argument and does nothing.

I remember having this problem before, and my teacher told me to back out of the directory and delete it from a directory above, but I have also tried that to no avail. Again, bash thinks I'm referring to an argument.

I seem to have gotten myself in quite a pickle. I know the solution is super simple but I can't seem to figure it out for myself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a

```
git rm -r -- --force
```

(instead of just `rm`)

That will not only remove it from the working tree, it will also removes it from the git index.
If that folder wasn't added to the index, then `rm -rf -- --force` is enough)

See "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)" for the explanation  of the double hyphen syntax: it separates the command from the file arguments.

Comment: Referring to the directory as `./--force` is another solution.