# Remove file called --a from git

Tags: git, rm

I accidentially created and committed a file called `--a` in my git repository. Using `git rm --a` obviously did not work. How can I remove this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
git rm ./--a
```

This can be used to remove any file with the name starts with '-'

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
git rm -- --a
```

The `--` helps separating the command from the parameters

See more on the double hyphen syntax in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".