# Guidelines or standards for command line interfaces (CLI)

Tags: command-line-interface

Are there generic rules or guidelines meant to improve the ease of use or user experience with a command line interface (CLI)?

Maybe even some attempt at standardization?

In my case I'm trying to follow the ideas of `git` and I'm using Python with the `click` package which already sets some "framework".

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/standard-options.html There are just standards, you are free to do as you want. It's just that if you don't present as it is done in lots of cli programs, your users will be annoyed.

Comment: The GNU Project has some [CLI standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html), which are based on the POSIX standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take example on [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) (used by docker or kubernetes) as an example of a complete CLI framework, one with:

- standard help/usage message
- [commands](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#commands) and sub-commands
- [POSIX flags](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#flags) (see [naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41898391/6309), which refers to the [GNU Standards for Command Line Interfaces](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html))
- [double-hyphen flag terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)
- [bash completion](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/1e58aa3361fd650121dceeedc399e7189c05674a/bash_completions.md)

Most of those are also implemented with [Python click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#basic-concepts).

Answer (score 2):

We created [clig.dev](https://clig.dev/) for this purpose.