# Naming convention for posix flags

Tags: linux, coding-style, posix, flags

I'm writing a console application which allows several Posix flags to be set.

This is what I'm using currently. Words in the flags are concatenated with a dash:

```
  -p, --broker-port int     Broker Port (default 1883)
  -u, --broker-url string   Broker URL (default "localhost")
  -c, --client-id string    MQTT Client Id
  -r, --room string         Room where sensor is located (default "myroom")
  -f, --floor string        Floor, where room is located (default "basement")
```

However I have also seen applications using CamelCase to concatenate pflags.

The official [GNU coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html) does not specify how to concatenate words in posix flags.

**What is the right way?**

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer seems to be buried in the GNU docs [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html).

> GNU adds long options to these conventions. Long options consist of
>   ‘--’ followed by a name made of alphanumeric characters and dashes.
>   **Option names are typically one to three words long, with hyphens to
>   separate words**. Users can abbreviate the option names as long as the
>   abbreviations are unique.

What you've got follows the convention; camel case does not.