# Git fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch_name': both revision and filename

Tags: git

I have two branch and two file have same name,like

```
branch:  
  branch_1  
  branch_2  

file:  
  branch_1  
  branch_2
```

Now I want use command

```
git log branch_1 --not branch_2
```

See the commit in `branch_1` but not in `branch_2`, I find I can't find a solution get the right result.
I know I can use '`--`' tell git '`branch_1`' is a branch not a file like

```
git log --oneline branch_1 -- --not branch_2 --
```

but I still don't get the right result, I even don't know what the output is.

I also know

```
git log --oneline branch_2..branch_1
```

give what I want. But I curiously. Is

```
git log branch_1 --not branch_2
```

can't treat situation like this? Or is a solution I don't know?

Answer (score 3):

`git log branch_1 --not branch_2 --` should work.

Your example (which didn't work) was:

```
git log --oneline branch_1 -- --not branch_2 --
                           ^^
                          wrong
```

It should have been:

```
git log --oneline branch_1 --not branch_2 --
```

When you use  only *one* '`--`' at the end, you signal git that whatever follow is a file.
See [more about the double-hyphen convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309).