# How to add a folder to the .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, bower, gitignore, git-bash

Maybe my Googling skills are lacking but this seems like a question that should give me back thousands of hits and yet, I can't find a straight answer.

Simple as this:

I do constant pushes to github to share with a remote developer. We both have `npm` and `bower` installed. No need to push these huge folders to github all the time. My `node_modules` are ignored. But I can't seem to get `gitignore` to ignore my `bower_components` folder

I'm not too savvy on cmd, I barely scratch the surface so if you ar going to suggest that, please don't assume I know what you are talking about. Otherwise if it is as easy as adding it to the file itself using an IDE, well, I did that and no cigar. Here is my .gtignore file for your review

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-    task-files)
.grunt

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules
jspm_packages
bower_components

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history
```

Am I missing anything? How do I make the bower_components ignored?

Thank you

Comment: Possibly see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/4494

Comment: @MattW. Thank you for this link. This also helped me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to ignore folder, you need a trailing slash:

```
bower_components/
```

Then check if the rule apply with [`git check-ignore -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (the `-v` is important if you want to see the exact `.gitignore` file and line which causes a file to be ignored)

```
git check-ignore -v -- bower_components/afile
```

If that does not apply, then remove the content of that folder from the history of that repo:

```
git rm --cached -r -- bower_components/
git add .
git commit -m "Remove bower_components folder"
```

Then the `.gitignore` rule will take effect immediatly.

---

When you see `--`, the double-dash separates command-line options from the list of files (useful when filenames might be mistaken for command-line options).
See more at "[Unix style double-hyphen '`--`', and Gnu style triple-hyphen '`---`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

Comment: Thank you for your response. The first set of instructions returned no errors. and the check ignore did identify that line 32 contained an ignore rule for bower but on commit, the bower folder remained in github. So I assume that your last set of instructions are for removing that from github but it returned an error where pathspec "rr" did not match any files. Am I supposed to replace rr for  bower_components

Comment: @LOTUSMS Sorry, it was a type: `-r` (for `--recursive`), *before* the `--`

Comment: @LOTUSMS And that last set of instruction of for removing that folder from the index, locally. Not from GitHub. You would need to push your branch to GitHub for GitHub to reflect your local repo history.

Comment: lol. I figured, after I checked out the link someone commented above. But your question did help me. Thank you very much. Hopefully this question/answer gets a lot of visibility. It's basically the only straight answer in the internet so far

Comment: Right. That's what I meant. I did a commit and it is all great now!

Comment: how's -v important? it is just the reporting level

Comment: @A_P That I prefer always using `-v`, because it reports the actual `.gitignore` path and the line within that `.gitignore`, when a file is ignored. Without `-v`, it just prints the file if it is ignored, but you don't know what `.gitignore` directive is actually involved.

Comment: @VonC exactly my point. But your answer makes it look as if it will not work without -v.

Comment: @A_P It won't be useful without. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Vonc what does the double dash '--' do? (git rm --cached -r -- bower_components/)

Comment: Thanks. I got it from git rm --help
       --
           This option can be used to separate command-line options from the list of files, (useful when filenames might be mistaken for command-line options).

Comment: @YBai Sorry for the late answer. I documented the double hyphen syntax back in 2009: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309