# git add submodule into existing directory

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules, git-clone

I have a git repository in the parent folder. Lets call this folder "root".
Then there is a sub directory in the folder, lets call it "child". What I want to do is clone a remote repository as a submodule into "child":

```
git submodule add git@github.com:username/repopath child/
git submodule add git@github.com:username/repopath ./child/
```

Both the above give me the error:

> child already exists in the index

I tried removing the directory from being tracked:

```
git rm --cached .\child\*
git submodule add git@github.com:username/repopath child/
```

Then i get this error:

> 'child' already exists and is not a valid git repo

Any help would be most appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First, try your submodule add command in a new clone, because your previous attempts might have left a partial state for submodule.

Second, try first

```
git rm -r --cached child
```

Then, add and commit.

Finally, try your [`git submodule` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
git submodule add -- git@github.com:username/repopath child
```

Add, and commit.

Comment: For learners, `git submodule add -- git@github.com:username/repopath child`. `--`: after the two dashes, there are only folders and files, no options. `git@githu...` is a `ssh` address, not `https`.

Comment: @Timo For more on the double hyphen (or double dash): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: Huge thanks to @VonC for your answer and comment. Very useful