# Deleting a Git branch where the name contains a pipe (|) character

Tags: git

I've been unable to delete this branch from the origin directly, or by creating a local copy.

Sample branch name: `sample-branch|name`.

A `git pull` returns `Unable to create 'D:/my/git/repo/.git/refs/remotes/origin/sample-branch|name.lock': Invalid argument: Invalid argument`

A `git checkout sample-branch|name` returns `error: pathspec 'sample-branch|name' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Using the git branch -d --.... suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch), have also failed.

Is there an alternative command or a change to the existing commands that can be used in this instance?

Edit 1: I have tried with and without quotes

Comment: Can you show the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: And can you clarify what operating system/environment you're on? Looks like Windows, are you using something like Git Bash?

Comment: And please show exactly all the commands you've tried, and the complete corresponding error messages.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/270004/how-to-escape-pipe-symbol-in-bat-scripts - Maybe you could try using `sample-branch^|name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch -d|D` is only applicable for local branches. To delete a remote branch, you need to use slightly different command.

```
git push origin --delete "sample-branch|name" # git version >= 1.7

git push origin :"sample-branch|name" # for older versions
```

Comment: Try it with origin specified.

Comment: Perhaps the branch doesn't really exist with the same name. Try running `git remote show origin | grep -i sample-branch`

Comment: Running that shows the branch is listed and tracked.

Comment: `git branch -D origin/"sample-branch|name"` - Last guess then.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but still no joy with the latest suggestion.

Comment: @ManxJason My bad. We were using wrong command for deletion. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Since version 1.7, this new syntax has been added as well.

Comment: Both of those threw an error, however the branch was deleted in the process. Thanks for your help