# git diff fatal: ambiguous argument unknown revision or path not in working tree

Tags: fatal-error, git-diff, git

I am running *git fetch origin* in my production code and then am trying to a Git diff with my current branch with *origin/master*. I am facing this error while running the command:

> fatal: ambiguous argument unknown revision or path not in working tree

Please find below the command used and the actual error.

Command tried:

```
git fetch origin
git diff --name only release/test origin/master
```

Expected output:

```
git diff should work
```

Actual output:

```
[localhost] local: git diff --name-only release/test origin/master |   ambiguous argument 'release/test': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

How can we correct the issue with my Git diff command?

Comment: Is `release/test` actually a branch in your repository? What happens if you do `git show release/test`?

Comment: yeah the branch is part of my repository.

Comment: What happens if you add a `--` to the end of your command (`git diff --name-only release/test origin/master --`)?

Comment: It throws fatal: bad revision 'releast/test' while trying git diff --name-only release/test origin/master -- @Amber

Comment: Okay, what happens if you do `git fetch release`? If that works, try the `diff` again?

Comment: Is this a typo?: `--name only`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you don't have:

- Either a path within your Git repository folder which would match the branch name, that is a folder `release/test`
- or, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586154/git-diff-fatal-ambiguous-argument-unknown-revision-or-path-not-in-working-tree/54586711#comment109151979_54586711) by [philant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18804/philant), a branch name matching the path of the file being diffed,
- or a tag matching the branch name: `git tag -l` (Listing `release/test`)

Adding `--` would make sure the two branch names are [interpreted as literals, not options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309). In this case ([`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203)), as paths, not commits or other `git diff` options.

```
git diff --name-only release/test origin/master --
```

In your case, this should fail unless you actually have paths/folders named `release/test` and `origin/master`.

So `git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit>` remains the correct syntax. 
You only need to make sure there is no path or tag already named like one of those two commits.

Comment: For `git diff` double dashes `--` [separate](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) commits from paths, not options from paramaters.

Comment: @phd Agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly. I remembered https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309.

Comment: I am getting git diff --name-only release/test origin/master -- ->Fatal : bad revision 'release/test' error.

Comment: @ManigandanThanigaiArasu can you check the output of git `tag -l`? Do you see a `release/test` in there?

Comment: Code used : ^local('git tag -l') : am getting Indentation error unexpected Indent

Comment: Could also be a branch name matching the path of the file being diffed.

Comment: @philant Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was first to checkout the branch, and then `git diff` commands would work.

```
$ git diff --name-only master...release/v1.1

fatal: ambiguous argument 'master...release/v1.1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'


$ git diff --name-only master release/v1.1 --

fatal: bad revision 'release/v1.1'


$ git checkout release/v1.1

Switched to a new branch 'release/v1.1'
Branch 'release/v1.1' set up to track remote branch 'release/v1.1' from 'origin'.


$ git diff --name-only master release/v1.1

foo
bar
```

Comment: It looks like that worked because you didn't have a local copy of release/v1.1.  Another option would have been to use "origin/release/v1.1"

Answer (score 0):

Use `git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master` before executing `git diff ...`