# What is a "switch" in a Git command?

Tags: git

I was reading a book which shows the syntax of git commands as:
[image]

[image]

so my question is,  is `--global` also a switch? Can a switch also a argument?

Updated:

the book said `--global` is a switch, so I assume `-a` is also a switch and we can use it as `git help -a`, but we can't use it as `git -a help`, which is supposed to be valid according to the syntax?

Comment: it's an argument, you're telling git what is the target config that will be updated (unlike, for example, when you install a dependency globally)

Comment: @ffflabs  so why this argument needs to prefixed as `--global`, but other arguments don't? for example, `--user.name`?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/q/1074694

Comment: Git recently added a `git switch` command, used to switch branches. This is *not* what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I think it is more common to call these *options* rather than *switches*, but both terms are in use.

Comment: @slowjams Did my answer clarified your question? `user.name` is an argument (no `--`), not an option or switch `--xx`. SO there is no `--user.name`, because `user.name` is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switches are all the parameters passed *before* any Git actual command: see [`docs/git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git)

```
git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
    [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
    [-p|--paginate|-P|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
    [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
    [--super-prefix=<path>]
    <command> [<args>]
```

You can see all the possible switches before `<command> [<args>]`

`--global` is a switch for the [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) command as [seen here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git%20config%20--global%20--list), not for "`git`" alone.

The term "switch" was introduced in [commit 0a8365a; May 2005, Git v0.99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a8365a179685feecee427075a9c2db8a66c434a)

> ### `diff-tree`: fix and extend argument parsing
>
> We use "`--`" to mark end of **command line switches**, not "`-`".

This is inline with the [double-hyphen command-line convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309), which is, as [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309), useful if a non-option argument starts with a hyphen.

```
                       -- optional separator, followed by arguments
                       v
git -p config --global -- user.name
    ^^        ^^^^^^^^
     |            |_ switch for the git config subcommand.
     |
  switch for the git command
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my case, `--global` is passed after the actual command(`config`), isn't that `--global` should be passed before any Git actual command as you mentioned?

Comment: @slowjams No it should not: it is the `--global` of `git config` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---global. `git --global` does not exist.

Comment: But isn't that a switch should appear before the command? but for `git config --global`, the switch  is after the command?

Comment: @slowjams no: it is a switch for the `git config` command, not for `git` itself. `git` itself how no `--global` switch. `git config` does, as per the link I have put: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---global

Comment: you mean `git config` is a command? isn't that a command is only a single word(e.g `config` is a command)? Even though `git config` is a command, the `--global switch` is still after the command, not before the command.

Comment: @slowjams yes git config is a command (a sub command of git itself): read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt

Comment: OK, so for `git config`, the switch `--global` can be after the actual command? As `git config --global`, clearly the switch is after the `git config` command. I am really confused

Comment: Each command has its own set of switch. Git itself has some, git config has some.

Comment: @slowjams Why did you select an answer which was just a cheap copy of mine?

Comment: I think you edited your answer later which is more clear to me, thanks

Comment: I have selected your answer. Another question is that isn't that single hyphen sometimes the same as single hyphen? like `-g` is the same as `--global`?

Comment: @slowjams yes, it is a convention where a single hyphen designates a single letter option, alias for a word option. A word option (like 'global') is prefixed by a double-hypen. See the answers of https://serverfault.com/q/387935/783 or https://askubuntu.com/q/813303/5470

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a command line argument that begins with a hyphen is called a switch. (But even with this "definition", I would consider the word "switch" jargon in this context rather than a technical term.)

A "switch" typically changes a minor aspect of a command or its mode of operation.

Since the `git` command has many sub-commands, you can have switches that apply to the command in general (these are the switches between `git` and the subcommand) and switches that apply to the sub-command (these occur after the sub-command).

Given your example

```
git -p config --global user.name "Rick"
```

- `-p` is a switch that applies to the command in general;
- `--global` is a switch that applies to the sub-command.