# How to `git blame --ignore-revs-file` on a bare git repository

Tags: git, blame, git-blame

The command `git blame --ignore-revs-file .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt` works on a non-bare repository locally on my machine but when I get the bare repository for the same repository locally and try the same command, the following happens:

```
git blame --ignore-revs-file .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt
fatal: could not open object name list: .git-blame-ignore-revs
```

Also noted that it works when we pass the same content in a copied file sitting somewhere else in the file system.
Eg: `git blame --ignore-revs-file /tmp/.git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt` works fine.

I thought this might be because its not able to find the path mentioned in bare repository and so I tried something like the following:

`git blame --ignore-revs-file -- .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt`

but that resulted in :
 `fatal: bad revision '.git-blame-ignore-revs'`

Could anyone help me understand how do we pass file paths to options in git command while running it against bare repositories? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit: ah. I get it. You **want** to use the committed version of that file. Repo content in a bare clone ordinarily never exists as a separate file, history is sent in packs. You have to ask git to show itself the contents of that committed file:

```
git blame --ignore-revs-file <(git show @:.git-blame-ignore-revs) add.txt
```

or for purity points, howitzer-proof futureproofing and a few microseconds of speed,

```
git blame --ignore-revs-file <(git cat-file blob @:.git-blame-ignore-revs) add.txt
```

---

When I do this, it works:

```
sh -x <<\EOD; rm -rf deleteme
git init --bare deleteme; cd $_
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100000,$(git hash-object -w config),add.txt
git --work-tree . commit -m-
git log --oneline --name-status
> .git-blame-ignore-revs
git blame --ignore-revs-file .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt
EOD
```

and when I do

```
sh -x <<\EOD; rm -rf deleteme
git init --bare deleteme; cd $_
git update-ref HEAD $(git commit-tree -m - $(git mktree <&-))
> .git-blame-ignore-revs
git blame --ignore-revs-file .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt
EOD
```

the error message is `fatal: no such path add.txt in HEAD`.

So I think your first test really didn't have that ignore list present.

Comment: Curious to understand how the second option there `or for purity points, howitzer-proof futureproofing and a few microseconds of speed,` would save few microseconds.

Comment: `git show` is "porcelain", implemented by `git log` (it's basically `git log --no-walk -p`) which does its full setup, including scanning the configs for all its tweaks plus all of `git diff`s.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> git blame --ignore-revs-file -- .git-blame-ignore-revs add.txt
> ```
>
> but that resulted in :  `fatal: bad revision '.git-blame-ignore-revs'`
>
> I asked the question to understand if it is possible to used the checked in file in the repo.

Yes, but the syntax of [`git blame --ignore-revs-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---ignore-revs-fileltfilegt) is:

```
git blame --ignore-revs-file <file>  -- <file>
```

Meaning:

- the first `<file>` (before the [double-hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)) is your `.git-blame-ignore-revs`
- the second `<file>` (after the double-hypen) is your file to blame on.

By putting `.git-blame-ignore-revs` *after* `--`, you forced the `git` command to consider it as a "non-option argument".

---

In a bare repository, though, there is no working tree, so `--ignore-revs-file` has no actual file to reference.

Answer (score 2):

The same command works for me even with a bare repository. The prerequisite is that the file `.git-blame-ignore-revs` must exist in the current directory (where the bare repo exists).

Note that even if the file `.git-blame-ignore-revs` was checked into the repo, the file must be present in the file system in the path specified by the `--ignore-revs-file` option.

It's likely that you were getting the error simply because the file `.git-blame-ignore-revs` was absent in the current directory.

Comment: `Note that even if the file .git-blame-ignore-revs was checked into the repo, the file must be present in the file system in the path specified by the --ignore-revs-file option.`

This is already known. As I stated in the question, it works when the file is present somewhere else in the file system. I asked the question to understand if it is possible to used the checked in file in the repo.

Comment: No it's not possible, AFAIK.