# Create clearcase dynamic view using CAL in C#

Tags: c#, clearcase

I'm trying to create a clearcase dynamic view using CAL in C# using the following code.

```
private static ClearCase.ClearTool ct;

string viewName = "tmp_view";

string cmd = "mkview –tag "+ viewName + " –stream " + selectedStream +"@"+ projectVob + "  \\\\<Network Shared Path>\\"+ viewName +".vws";

ct.CmdExec(cmd);
```

On execution, ct.CmdExec method throws exception saying viewTag must be specified.

For the same cmd string I'm able to create a view using cleartool command prompt.

Can you please tell me why I'm unable to create a view in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you didn't used `-tag` but `–tag`: replace '`–`' (minus) by '`-`' (hyphen minus).
Note: same for `–stream`: use `-stream`.

[image: plus minus hypen-minus]

(plus , minus , hyphen-minus)

See [What's the toughest bug you ever found and fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed/170148#170148) :

> - "Hyphen-minus" is the regular familiar character on keyboards, `ASCII 45` and `U+002D`, (ab)used in both "`5-4=1`" and "`vice-versa`".
> - The actual minus sign, which is longer, is `U+2212` and is not in ASCII.

It is typical of IBM documentation which, unfortunately, use minus (the long '–'): any copy-paste coming from their page doesn't work immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. It worked for me. I used Convert.ToChar(45) instead of using "-".