# Docker: `Repository name must match ...` error

Tags: docker

I'm reading the book `Docker in action`, which is a really great book so far, but I think I'm stuck now on a command which doesn't work

```
$> docker run –it --rm --link cass1:cass cassandra:2.2 cqlsh cass
```

It should run an interactive shell (`cqlsh`) on the cassandra database, but when I run this I get the following error:

```
repository name component must match "[a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*)*"
```

Any suggestions why this doesn't work ?

Comment: Which version of docker are you running? `docker info`

Comment: Can you try to enter the command manually as it is written? There might be a hidden character in your command that your shell is not showing.

Comment: Yes, thats it, Thanks. When I copy-past it from the book, it doesn't work, but when I type it over it work!!

Answer (score 1):

The [single cassandra example](https://github.com/jimthedev/cassandra-1#single-cassandra-node) mentions this docker run command *after*

> Launch a server called `cass1`:

Make sure you have a cass1 container up *and running* before trying a `--link cass1:cass`, or the last "`cass`" argument would reference nothing.

---

Regarding the command-line error, this is very similar to [minus vs.  hyphen minus error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834854/6309): both characters looks the same in monospaced font, but the minus would not be correctly interpreted by a shell..

Comment: Yep, `cass1` is up and running, it shows up when I do `docker ps`

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri then the questions in the comments do apply: please edit your question.