# Script exits after view is set (clearcase)

Tags: shell, clearcase

I am trying to run a shell script. Inside the script, I need to set the view:

```
ct setview viewname
```

then run some commands. What happens is that after the view is set, the script exits. I also tried the following as suggested in other posts:

```
cleartool setview -exec script viewname
cleartool: Error: View tag not found: ", -exec, "
```

I also tried the full path for `cleartool`. Didn't work!

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned before in "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview)", using [`setview`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) in a script is generally not a good idea.
It will create a subshell, which will cause any running script to exit once that subshell exits.

If you can, use the full dynamic view path (`/view/myView/vobs/myVob/...`): you are then sure in that path to run as many scripts/commands as you want.
As long as the dynamic view is started and the vob mounted, you don't need `setview`.

If you do need `setview`:

- `cleartool setview -exec script viewname`: make sure you type yourself the '`-`' in `-exec`, and don't copy-paste it. That is because of the [hyphen-minus bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309) I illustrate in [ClearCase question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834854/6309).
- try do set the view, then run your script (two steps, as [I recommend here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18457541/6309))