# Clearcase CMI Integration mkcmprovider command doesn't recognize -options

Tags: clearcase

I am using BASE Clearcase with CMI integration.
In the mkcmprovider command, if I use -options, then the command fails due to unrecognized token called '-options'.
But the Clearcase 8.0x manual says that the -options keyword is valid inside mkcmprovider.
**Following is the VERSION information of my server:**

```
   M:\DevView\Test>cleartool -version  
   ClearCase version 8.0.1.00 (Mon May 27 15:08:54 EDT 2013) (8.0.1.D130526)  
   @(#) MVFS version 8.0.1.0 (Wed May 15 14:57:16 2013)  
   cleartool                         8.0.1.0 (Wed May 15 21:46:14 2013)  
   db_server                         8.0.1.0 (Wed May 15 18:40:45 2013)  
   VOB database schema versions: 54, 80
```

**Following is the error:**

```
   M:\DevView\Test>cleartool mkcmprovider -brtype main -replace -options ciVerifyPr
ov:true,ciVerifyUser:true,reqProvTask:true CQPROV  
   cleartool: Error: Unrecognized option "-options"  
   Usage: mkcmprovider {-vob vob-selector | -replica replica-selector} `enter code here`[-replace]
                    {-data prov-info-file | -type <type> -version <version> -des
cription <description>
                    -connection <connection_info>} provider_name
       mkcmprovider {-brtype <brtype-name>} [-replace]
                    [{-data context-info-file | -context <context-string>}] prov
ider_name
```

Comment: Reference Link for mkcmprovider -options command ::  How to use the Change Management Integration (CMI) Policy Keywords  :: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21680545

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to actually type the '`-`' of '`-options`' instead of copying it from the [IBM documentation for `cleartool mkcmprovider`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkcmprovider.htm?lang=en).

The doc has only has [a minus instead of the hyphen-minus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309).

However, in this case, `-options` is only supported from 8.0.1.5: see the [8.0.1.X release notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27037036#whatsnew8013).

> ### What's New
>
> This release introduces the following features.
>
> #### Change management interface (CMI)
>
> The following enhancements to CMI are introduced in this release:
>
> - CMI supports the configuration of Rational Team Concert state transitions; for instructions, refer to Configuring CMI for Rational Team Concert state transitions.
> - **The `mkcmprovider` command supports policy configuration for base ClearCase and UCM; for complete information, [refer to the command reference page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkcmprovider.htm?lang=en)**.
> - ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) supports CMI independent of the RTC bridge for dynamic views only.

Comment: I already typed 'MINUS' instead of 'UNDERSCORE' for -options keyword.

Comment: @user3806728 I have edited/completed the answer. It seems `-options` is only from 8.0.1.5+.