# Why is Vundle asking for my github password?

Tags: github, vim, vundle

I entered my github password when installing plugins with vundle and I don't know what it was for.

I'm new with vim and i'm trying to install plugins with vundle so I modified mi vimrc file to include plugins and then ran `:PluginInstall" where one of the plugins asked for my github user and password, and I typed it in but now I don't know who I gave that password to or what for, does anyone know? should I change my password?

This is part of my vimrc file

```
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'                                                                                                                                
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'                                                                                                                                  
Plugin 'jakedouglas/exuberant-ctags'                                                                                                                        
Plugin 'junegunn/fzf'                                                                                                                                       
Plugin 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim'                                                                                                                             
Plugin 'Townk/vim-autoclose'                                                                                                                                
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
```

Comment: If you don’t know, change your password. Ive only had git tools ask for passwords when pushing over ssh and the ssh key wasn’t set up. You shouldnt be pushing with pluginstall. So honestly, who knows

Comment: git will ask for your password if you try to clone an https URL, because it's authenticating with username and password, not your private keys

Answer (score 2):

> I typed it in but now I don't know who I gave that password to or what for,

This should be strictly local: check your `git config credential.helper` value: that is probably Git asking for your credentials to cache them, avoiding to ask them every time.

As to *why* Vundle triggered that credential request... see [`google/vim-maktaba` issue 160](https://github.com/google/vim-maktaba/issues/160)

> Sorry guys, there was a typo in the plugin name ([en dash instead of hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309)). Fixed it and works now.