# Docker:"invalid reference format" in Powershell

Tags: docker

I have pulled a node js image from the docker hub and with node express generator I generated a little sample site.
I want to create a volume inside a Docker container and map the site folder with that volume.

I want to run the node from the docker container.
I am using this command:

```
docker run -p 8003:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Which of the two suggestions was it in your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check if you have typed or copy-pasted the docker run command.
In the later case, re-type the '-' (dash) manually in order to [avoid using by mistake a minus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309)

```
 docker run -p 8003:3000 -v
           ^^^          ^^^
 type manually *all* those '-'
```

Second, check if the `$(pwd)` should be, in a Powershell session, `-v ${PWD}` instead.