# Cannot SSH to Oracle Cloud Instance

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Goal: Trying to access Oracle Cloud Instance from Mac terminal.

SSH Command I am using:

```
ssh –i <private_key_file> username @ public ip address of instance
```

And it gives:

```
Error:  ssh: Could not resolve hostname ?\200\223i: 
        nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I am following this manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/accessinginstance.htm

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you follow the tutorial which includes:

```
ssh –i <private_key_file> <username>@<public-ip-address>
```

Make sure you do not  use the long `–` in `–i`, but type manually the regular minus '`-`'

A [long dash](https://graphemica.com/%E2%80%93) has an octal escape sequence of `\342\200\223`, which could explain the `\200\223` you see in your output.

Comment: That throws me back to [oct. 2008!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170148/6309)

Comment: Thanks Von, I really appreciate your help.